# About display panels with checkbox selected

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcheckbox

I'm learning java Swing now and I got this demo code from online tutorial. You can display 4 panels with different color(red,blue,green,yellow) once you select the corresponding checkboxs. 
But what if I want to select 4 colors from 6("red","blue","green","yellow","black","white") checkboxs, how to make amendment base on this demo?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CheckBoxExample_UltraExtended implements  ActionListener{

    JCheckBox redCB, blueCB, greenCB, yellowCB;
    JPanel redBox, blueBox, greenBox, yellowBox;
    JButton refresh;

    public JPanel createContentPane (){

        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();

        // We create four checkboxes to control what is currently on-screen.
        // At the start, we set the red checkbox to 'ticked' or selected.

        JPanel checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();
        checkBoxPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(checkBoxPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        checkBoxPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10,0)));

        redCB = new JCheckBox("Red");
        redCB.setSelected(true);

        checkBoxPanel.add(redCB);
        checkBoxPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        blueCB = new JCheckBox("Blue");        
        checkBoxPanel.add(blueCB);
        checkBoxPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        greenCB = new JCheckBox("Green");
        checkBoxPanel.add(greenCB);
        checkBoxPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

        yellowCB = new JCheckBox("Yellow");
        checkBoxPanel.add(yellowCB);
        checkBoxPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));

        // Now we create a simple JPanel that displays our four coloured boxes.

        JPanel boxPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 20, 20));

        redBox = createSquareJPanel(Color.red, 50);
        blueBox = createSquareJPanel(Color.blue, 50);
        greenBox = createSquareJPanel(Color.green, 50);
        yellowBox = createSquareJPanel(Color.yellow, 50);

        // This sets all bar the red box to be hidden.

        blueBox.setVisible(false);
        greenBox.setVisible(false);
        yellowBox.setVisible(false);

        boxPanel.add(redBox);
        boxPanel.add(blueBox);
        boxPanel.add(greenBox);
        boxPanel.add(yellowBox);

        // Now lets quickly add a refresh button with an actionListener to determine
        // when it is pressed.

        refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
        refresh.addActionListener(this);

        totalGUI.add(checkBoxPanel);
        totalGUI.add(boxPanel);
        totalGUI.add(refresh);

        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    // In this method, we create a square JPanel of a colour and set size
    // specified by the arguments.

    private JPanel createSquareJPanel(Color color, int size) {
        JPanel tempPanel = new JPanel();
        tempPanel.setBackground(color);
        tempPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        tempPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        tempPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size, size));
        return tempPanel;
    }

    // This actionPerformed simply takes sets the visibility of each
    // coloured box to the state of each checkbox.

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == refresh)
        {
            redBox.setVisible(redCB.isSelected());
            blueBox.setVisible(blueCB.isSelected());
            greenBox.setVisible(greenCB.isSelected());
            yellowBox.setVisible(yellowCB.isSelected());
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JCheckBox [=]");

        CheckBoxExample_UltraExtended demo = new CheckBoxExample_UltraExtended();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to restrict selection of more then 4 check boxes?

Comment: yes, 6 selections of color but only display no more than 4 panels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to `addActionListener` to the check boxes like this.

Take a `private` variable `numberOfCheckedBoxes` to track number of check box checked.

```
private numberOfCheckedBoxes = 0;
```

Now, when you create checkboxes, add action listener like this

```
redCB = new JCheckBox("Red");
redCB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (numberOfCheckedBoxes  == 4){
            JOptionMessage.showMessageDialog("Can not select more than 4 check boxes");
            return;
        }
        if (redCB.isSelected()){
            increaseNumberOfCheckedBoxes();
        }else{
            reduceNumberOfCheckedBoxes();
        }
    }
});
```

This you have to do for all check boxes you create. Now the other required methods.

```
public void increaseNumberOfCheckedBoxes(){
    numberOfCheckedBoxes ++;
}
public void reduceNumberOfCheckedBoxes(){
    numberOfCheckedBoxes --;
}
```

**Another approach is**, create a method `handleCheckBoxSelection`

```
public handleCheckBoxSelection(boolean isSelected){
    if (numberOfCheckedBoxes  == 4){
        JOptionMessage.showMessageDialog("Can not select more than 4 check boxes");
        return;
    }
    if (isSelected){
        increaseNumberOfCheckedBoxes();
    }else{
        reduceNumberOfCheckedBoxes();
    }
}
```

and then while initialising check boxes, call this function

```
redCB = new JCheckBox("Red");
redCB.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        handleCheckBoxSelection(redCB.isSelected());
    }
});
```